# Consider a seemingly ARMA(2,2) model

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima

Consider this seeming ARMA(2,2) model
$
X_t = (\phi - a)X_{t-1} + a\phi X_{t-2} + W_t + (a+\theta) W_{t-1} + a\theta W_{t-2}.
$

Put this model into terms of backshift operators and factor into $\phi(B)X_t = \theta(B)W_t$, dropping like terms. What are $p$ and $q$ actually in this ARMA(p,q) model?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you take any steps? Did you get stuck on the way?